# Java Changing Part of String with Specific Character

Tags: java, string, methods, replace, substring

I am trying to take a part of a String from point(a,b) and replace letters from given values in the string into 'X's.

Example: If the string is `ABC123` and `switch(3,5)` is called, it would change it to `ABCXXX`.

So far I have:

```
  public void switch(int p1, int p2)
{
   String substring = myCode.substring(p1,p2-1);
}
```

I am very lost....thanks for any help!

Comment: Should the XXX part or the returning word be a pre-defined word? Should it always be XXX, or sometimes XYZ or WXY?

Comment: You can't name your method `switch`. That's a reserved keyword in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `String`s are immutable and can not be changed. You could however, write a method that returns a `new String` with those characters marked out. A `StringBuilder` is a good class to familiarize yourself with as it allows for fast string manipulations.

StringBuilder documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

```
public class StringReplace {

    public static String replaceRange(String s, int start, int end){
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);

        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            b.setCharAt(i, 'x');

        return b.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "mystringtoreplace";
        String replaced = replaceRange(test, 3, 8);
        System.out.println(replaced);
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand this but this method is for an object that can only have two parameters (int, int). The substring that I am trying to replace comes from an object created in another class.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to update a reference not modify the actual string. In this example, rather than creating a new `String replaced` you could just do `test = replaceRange(test, 3, 8)` This would update your reference. So, your method might just take a `start` and `end` variable at which point you can do `myVar = replaceRange(myVar, start, end);`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder` and its `replace(int start, int end, String str)` method

Answer (score 0):

Just do two substrings for the left and the right hand parts (which you want to keep), then concat them with the appropriate number of Xs between.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Sub {

    public String replaceChar(String str, int x, int y){
        String temp = "XXX";
        String str1 = "";
        str1 = str.substring(x, y+1);
        str = str.replace(str1, temp);
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Sub s = new Sub();
        System.out.println(s.replaceChar("ABC123", 3, 5));
    }

}
```

Comment: A) don't just give them code. give them the tools they need to get the job done. B) make proper formatting for the question ("This is what you need to do, here's one way to do it: *insert code*. This works by *insert description*)

Comment: I tried and it worked and if they see the code in smal snippet they can understand better...and i formatted code by ctrl+K and submitted...i don't know what is formatting otherthan this???

Comment: Formatting as in how the question is presented

Comment: I Formastted as per Question and by the way soo many posts have pure code and no one obligated..final Step of this forum is help each other.. and get right answer..That is what exactly i did..as you formatted as sentenses of the same code and i formatted as code perceptive...please be nicer to people who are trying to help..

Comment: A) this is not a forum. Don't believe me, go on Meta. B) the goal is to help others advance in their coding abilities, not to give them code and ignore anything else. C) at least try to be professional about it, I'm not attacking you personally. D) I'm not attacking your answer, just trying to get it to fit better as to what SO is about.

Comment: please..i presented correct answer and top of that getting '-1' because of your obligations ..go head and Enjoy your coding skills don't attack personlly ..to who don't have repution to give '-'points to your same answer given like me

Comment: Actually, that wasn't my downvote

Comment: @BloodRed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154813/why-was-this-suggested-edit-rejected

Answer (score -1):

A few steps that might help:

1. Identify the number of characters you need changed
2. Identify the left side of the string you intend to keep (`str.substring(0,p1);`)
3. Identify the right side of the string you intend to keep (`str.substring(p2,str.length());`)
4. Put them together (`String output = firstPart + addedChars + secondPart;`)